# how to extract particular text using python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have one variable having value

```
ServerC = "WebSphere:cell=abc,cluster=Cluster1+WebSphere:cell=abc,cluster=Cluster2"
```

I want only all Cluster values in another variable 
I am trying to use

```
clusterN = ServerC.split("cluster=")
clusterN = clusterN[1]
```

but I am not getting required values

Comment: what do you mean by U&L

Comment: This is related to Python Scripting in Linux

Comment: "but I am not getting required values". What are you getting and what is it you want?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `re.findall()`:

```
import re
ServerC = "WebSphere:cell=abc,cluster=Cluster1+WebSphere:cell=abc,cluster=Cluster2"
pat = re.compile("cluster\=(\w+)")
print(pat.findall(ServerC))

# Output: ['Cluster1', 'Cluster2']
```